# How to use Ninject's NamedLikeFactoryMethod with parameters correctly?

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a C# Console application in which i use Ninject.

If I run it with the following code, the console says: "*A Dog with the name Dogy was created, he is 7 years old*".

This result is actualy fine to me since i passed 7 as a parameter in the Main()- method in Program.cs, but it feels like i dont use the Extension method "NamedLikeFactoryMethod" propperly in my "PettModul.cs" class since i can type in any string and integer as parameter and the result is still the same. Do i use the "NamedLikeFactoryMethod" wrong? If so, how do i use it propperly?

I Have the following code:

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(new TierModul());
        var factory = kernel.Get<IPetFactory>();
        var dogy = factory.GetDog("Dogy",7);            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Dog.cs**

```
public class Dog: IPet
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly int _age;        

    public Dog(string name, int age)
    {
        _age= age;
        _name = name;
        Console.WriteLine($"A Dog with the name {_name} was created, he is{_age} years old");
    }
}
```

**IPetFactory.cs**

```
 public interface IPetFactory
{
    IPet GetDog(string name, int age);
    IPet GetCat(string name);
}
```

**PetModul.cs**

```
public class PetModul : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {            
        Bind<IPet>().To<Dog>().NamedLikeFactoryMethod((IPetFactory f) => f.GetDog("name",1));           

        Bind<IHaustierFactory>().ToFactory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
Bind<IPet>().To<Dog>().NamedLikeFactoryMethod((IPetFactory f) => f.GetDog("name",1))
```

is equivalent to:

```
Bind<IPet>().To<Dog>().Named("Dog")
```

Ninject's convection is that once you name your factory method with 'Get' prefix, than this method goes for binding named as the rest of this method.

`NamedLikeFactoryMethod` is here just to avoid any hardcoded strings.

Comment: Ok, it just doesn't make any sense to me that i can type in any kind of parameter for `.GetDog("name",1)`, as long as its a string and int of course, but it still works. I see the idea behind it  to avoid any hardcoded strings but i think it would be more understandable if we could use types instead of values. For e.g. like `Bind<IPet>().To<Dog>().NamedLikeFactoryMethod((IPetFactory f) => f.GetDog<string,int>)`.

Comment: @AkurA87. that's because you just pass an expression to get out off the method name in strongly typed manner. Clearly any generic version as you proposed is not possible (you must provide real method of your factory).